# How to enable ohci debugging in linux kernel?

Tags: linux, usb

I am trying to enable ohci-dbg message in linux kernel there is a file under `drivers/usb/host/ohci-dbg.c` , How to enable those debug messages?

Answer (score 0):

You should recompile the `ohci` files (as module or as part of kernel) with debug macro enabled (-DDEBUG; also -DOHCI_VERBOSE_DEBUG).

The local macro DEBUG is also enabled if CONFIG_USB_DEBUG kernel build option is enabled (as of 3.10): http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/host/Makefile?v=3.10

```
Linux/drivers/usb/host/Makefile

  5 ccflags-$(CONFIG_USB_DEBUG) := -DDEBUG
```

You should also add `ohci-dbg.c` source file to the list of files to be compiled (it is not included in the Makefile of /usb/host).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the solution you described is working perfectly in 3.10 kernel. But i am using kernel 4.1, looks like CONFIG_USB_DEBUG is removed, how to define -DDEBUG in Makefile? in 4.1 kernel ohci-dbg.c file is included in ohci-hcd.c

Comment: For 4.1 you may add `CFLAGS_ohci-hcd.o := -DDEBUG ` in your makefile.